# Confuse about css pseudo selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I have a dom structure like this:

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="search"></div>
    <div class="scan"></div>

    <div class="topbook"></div> <!--select this one-->
    <div class="topbook"></div> 
    <div class="topbook"></div>
    <div class="topbook"></div>
</div>
```

and I want to use css pseudo selector to select the first `.topbook` element:

```
$("body .topbook:nth-of-type(1)").length // 0
```

but the select dom length is zero: http://jsfiddle.net/HGym3/

However, if I change the three head element's tag to `p`:

```
<div id="main">
    <p class="clear"></p>
    <p class="search"></p>
    <p class="scan"></p>

    <div class="topbook"></div> <!--select this one-->
    <div class="topbook"></div> 
    <div class="topbook"></div>
    <div class="topbook"></div>
</div>
```

the selector could work: http://jsfiddle.net/HGym3/1/

What's the difference? Does the `nth-of-type` selector related to tag type?

Comment: I understand this isn't what you want to do, but it works: just do `$('body .topbook')[index]`

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you're exactly right.  The `type` in `nth-of-type` is the tag.  [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-of-type).

A possibly easy fix is just to wrap your `.topbook` divs in another div; that will give you the effect you're looking for, without too much trouble.

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="clear"></p>
    <div class="search"></p>
    <div class="scan"></p>

    <div>
        <div class="topbook"></div> <!--select this one-->
        <div class="topbook"></div> 
        <div class="topbook"></div>
        <div class="topbook"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```